# issue compiling c code on linux (Missing headers)

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I am having issues compiling my code. It seems to an issue with the include headers

Here are my headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#define __KERNEL__
#include <asm/unistd.h>
```

Here's what I am using to compile:

```
gcc -o file file.c -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.12.0-kali2-common/include/asm-generic
```

I keep getting this error when I compile:

```
fatal error: uapi/asm-generic/signal.h: No such file or directory
#include <uapi/asm-generic/signal.h>
```

If I try adding asm/ or asm-generic/ to signal.h, I get:

```
redefinition of ‘struct timeval’
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `/asm-generic` from the `-I` option?  Have you got all the packages you need installed?  All the `-devel` packages?

Comment: It will go back to not being able to detect asm/page.h. Including that specific dir fixed asm/page.h exception.

Comment: What about if you include both, shorter one first?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems to me your are mixing headers intended for use by kernel modules with headers intended for use by userspace progams.

Comment: I am just trying to get my program to compile. I am trying to compile the code into an exe. I did not write this code. I am performing a pentest on a machine, and found this POC online. Haven't had too much luck...

Comment: ***`#define __KERNEL__`*** - WTF??? Why are you defining `__KERNEL__` for userland code?